# If statement error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' and out of order int()

Tags: python-3.x

My code is as follows:

```
allnums = []
odds = []
evens = []

number = 0

while True:
    number = input("Enter a number or type 'done':")

    if number.lower() == 'done':
        print("=============================")
        print("Your even numbers are", str(evens))
        print("Your odds numbers are", str(odds))
        print("=============================")
        print("Your smallest number is '"+str(allnums[0])+"'")
        break
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(number)
        evens.sort()
        allnums.append(number)
        allnums.sort()       
    if int(number) % 2 != 0:
        odds.append(number)
        odds.sort()
        allnums.append(number)
        allnums.sort()
    else:
        print("Invalid input")
```

I'm trying to create a program that reads a list of numbers and determines the lowest value, while also offering a list of even and odd numbers. I'm running into two issues with my code where the lowest number is not often correct, for example:

```
Enter a number or type 'done':33
Enter a number or type 'done':4
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':6
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':4
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':6
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':7
Enter a number or type 'done':44
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':88
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':done
=============================
Your even numbers are ['4', '4', '44', '6', '6', '88']
Your odds numbers are ['33', '7']
=============================
Your smallest number is '33'
```

I also get the following error when I use just a space(' ') as an answer, which I would like to write a print("Invalid input") response to something that is not a number or done, but always results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXX", line 17, in <module>
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

I know this has mostly to do with order of events, but what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allnums = []
odds = []
evens = []

number = 0

while True:
    try:
        number = input("Enter a number or type 'done':")

        if number.lower() == 'done':
            print("=============================")
            print("Your even numbers are", str(sorted(evens)))
            print("Your odds numbers are", str(sorted(odds)))
            print("=============================")
            print("Your smallest number is '"+str(sorted(allnums)[0])+"'")
            break
        elif int(number) % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(number)
            #evens.sort()
            allnums.append(number)
            #allnums.sort()       
        elif int(number) % 2 != 0:
            odds.append(number)
            #odds.sort()
            allnums.append(number)
            #allnums.sort()
        pass

    except:
        print("Invalid input")
    pass
```

are you sure, this is my output

```
deathnote@deathnote:~/Desktop/d$ python3 code.py 
Enter a number or type 'done':12
Enter a number or type 'done': 
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done': 
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':qwe
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':wqew
Invalid input
Enter a number or type 'done':done
=============================
Your even numbers are ['12']
Your odds numbers are []
=============================
Your smallest number is '12'
```

Comment: Still returns the same

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXXX", line 17, in <module>
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '`

Comment: are you sure, I tested it its, giving me perfect result.. wait pasting the output

Comment: Ahhh, I did not have the passes. Now results in clear invalid response. Awesome :)

Comment: Thanks , please upvote the answer so that others also follow it

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: `number` contains a space, which can't be parsed into an integer.  If you want to flag such input as invalid, you have to test it *before* trying to convert it to an integer (or catch the error that doing so generates).

Comment: What would you suggest adding/changing? I'm a tad dumbfounded as I've tried adding different testers but receive the same results.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. Need check for space before you are trying to get a number from it.
2. Then you are appending number input as string into your list, which will end with **wrong sorting result** as it will sort `string` instead of `number`.

---

```
allnums = []
odds = []
evens = []

number = 0

   if number.lower() == 'done':
    evens.sort()
    odds.sort()
    allnums.sort()
    print("=============================")
    print("Your even numbers are", str(evens))
    print("Your odds numbers are", str(odds))
    print("=============================")
    print("Your smallest number is '"+str(allnums[0])+"'")
    break

if number.isspace():
    print("Invalid input")
else:
    number = int(number)
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(number)
        allnums.append(number)
    elif int(number) % 2 != 0:
        odds.append(number)
        allnums.append(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
allnums = []
odds = []
evens = []

number = 0

while True:
    number = input("Enter a number or type 'done':")

    if number.lower() == 'done':
        print("=============================")
        print("Your even numbers are", str(evens))
        print("Your odds numbers are", str(odds))
        print("=============================")
        print("Your smallest number is '" + sorted(allnums)[0] + "'")
        break
    if not number.isnumeric():
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if int(number) % 2 == 0:
        evens.append(number)
        evens.sort()
        allnums.append(number)
        allnums.sort()
    if int(number) % 2 != 0:
        odds.append(number)
        odds.sort()
        allnums.append(number)
        allnums.sort()
```